# MPAndroidChart (LineChart) set alternative rendering

Tags: android, performance, render, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am using the `MPAndroidChart` (`LineChart`) component for displaying real time data. My client wants to see **all** data, which was captured by the android device. This can be an enormous amount of data! And after testing MPAndroid chart is only able to handle about 1500 datapoints on my nexus 7.

I know chart components in delphi, which shrink the datapoints by using the average of a specified range of points and displays.

Is there a method implemented in `MPAndroidChart`, which enables an algorithm like this? Or does anyone know an Android chart-component which includes this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
You have to add an Approximator to the Chart:

```
        double tolerance = 5;
        Approximator approximator = new Approximator(Approximator.ApproximatorType.DOUGLAS_PEUCKER,  tolerance);
        mChart.enableFiltering(approximator);
```